# Why are airlines against the transferring of tickets to other persons?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, regulations

Airlines usually either don't allow the transferring of tickets to another person after they've been purchased, or they do it at an extremely inflated price. What is the reason for doing this?

One idea I came up with would be to allow authorities to do background checks, but one could buy a ticket at the airport shortly before the flight. Of course, it would be more expensive and there would be the risk of a fully booked plane, but it is not impossible.

Comment: How about greediness? If you will not fly, they can just resell your ticket and get double amount of money. If you will give it to someone else, just normal amount of money?

Comment: @SalvadorDali : If I don't fly, how would they know it? By the time I fail to turn up at the check-in it would be too late to sell my ticket again.

Comment: They always sell more tickets then there are sits in the plane. They have some statistics how many people on average are missing the plane. So if on average for 100 sits 2 people are not coming, they are selling 102 sits. If everyone is coming, they just try to tell some 2 people "we are sorry, can you take another plane".

Comment: @SalvadorDali : this sounds more like a conspiracy theory. Any proof of this regularly occurring?

Comment: just write overbooking in google and you will see huge amount of such examples. This is not a conspiracy theory, this is just statistics. http://www.smartertravel.com/travel-advice/five-things-you-don-know-about-your-airline-ticket.html?id=4922087

Comment: @SalvadorDali When this happens, they often offer a cash reward to the passengers willing to take a later flight. It's still profitable.

Comment: @vsz - overbooking is totally and completely normal, yeah

Comment: A small factor - which maybe is too small to matter but maybe it's not, considering how hard many airlines try to scrap every single penny off customers - could be that the fewer passengers the plane carries, the lighter it would be, so the less fuel it would consume. Another thing, which instead is much more likely to matter, is that if the person who would have taken your ticket cannot do so, he/she is likely to buy a new ticket as he/she probably needs to fly anyway.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Airlines have a pricing strategy known as "yield management" or "revenue management" - they charge less for some seats than others, and expect these seats to be bought a long time in advance. They know that only a certain percentage of their customers are able to buy seats well in advance, and that those customers wouldn't fly if they couldn't get inexpensive seats.

A speculator could buy a $100 ticket and then offer it on eBay close to the flight date for $200. If more than half the seats this speculator bought were sold this way, the speculator would be making money. But the airline, which wants to sell seats close to the flight date for $500, would not. In fact very quickly the speculator enjoying selling 75% of tickets for $200 would see it fall to 0% because of another speculator selling them for $150, and then later another for $110 and so on. This is just how reselling markets tend to work.

By insisting that a ticket is not a commodity to be bought, traded, resold, and passed around from hand to hand, the airline is able to keep its complicated pricing structure in place. Overall, this is a good thing, because those last-minute high-price tickets cover a LOT of the cost of the flight - their existence is what keeps the long-advance-notice tickets so cheap!

Comment: (+1) It's also useful to enforce the “non-changeable” fares which is another price discrimination strategy. Also, the airline would be loosing at the other end too: Price-sensitive passenger might forgo travelling entirely because cheap tickets would be immediately bought by the speculators who hope to capture some of the airline's margin.

Comment: It's worth noting that event tickets such as concerts *are* treated as commodities, and that industry is completely FUBAR. I'm glad the same thing isn't affecting airlines...

Comment: @Thebluefish How so? More trading will reduce the bid/ask spread, right?

Comment: In the case of things such as concerts, "more trading" really means "The people who bought the cheap tickets first will almost always turn around and resell them for abnormally high prices". There's even now [a big controvery with restaraunt reservations](http://valleywag.gawker.com/1599984423) going on now with similar issues.

Comment: @Thebluefish a major difference is that in airlines the passengers and pilots don't suffer in any way if due to a failure of ticket allocation some plane goes half empty - but bands and concertgoers do get a worse experience in such cases.

Comment: Great answer! also airlines are trying to avoid this being done by thier own employees, where an employee can let his family members/friends buy tickets in bulk an sell them as you described, since the employee is an insider he/she can make a fortune out of this while that's a lost money for the airline.

Comment: While I'm not commenting on your explanaition, I do sort of disagree with the personal opinions. "Overall, this is a good thing, because those last-minute high-price tickets cover a LOT of the cost of the flight". By this line of thinking, when a new IPhone is launched, the first 100 pruchases should be at 5 bucks a phone, and the ones sold 3  month later should cost 2500 dollars. However Apple doesn't do that, and it seems to be working ok for them.

Comment: No, that's the other way round (hint: you book plane tickets *before* the plane leaves; you buy an iPhone *after* it's launched). The customers for whom time is critical - those who *must* fly tomorrow, or those who *must* have the latest iPhone - pay more. (In fact Apple doesn't tend to hike then cut the price of new iPhones over a short space of time, but in general technology products drop in price as time goes by after launch.)

Comment: And re Kate's opinion: it's a good thing if you can plan your travel well in advance; it's a bad thing if you often need to travel at short notice.

Comment: Does [airlines' big ancillary revenue](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andrewbender/2014/09/09/airline-profits-are-up-thanks-to-everything-but-airfares/) [needed to support otherwise diminishing profits from  ticket sales](http://www.economist.com/blogs/economist-explains/2014/02/economist-explains-5) also support the fact that their ticket pricing scheme is "good"? Also, returning to the general note, why doesn't pre-ordering of things use this same principle, or suffer from the fact that it lets you "change owner"/resell the preordered product later on?

Comment: If we could speculate, I'd be buying as many SYD-AKL flights for  Christmas as I could afford, and resell for more 2 months out. SO many Kiwis return home for the festive season and there aren't enough flights.

Comment: Airlines don't have their pricing structure as some sort of public service, @ShivanDragon. They have it because it makes them money given the strange mix of customers they attract. And many of their rules support their pricing structure. The fact that Apple has a different pricing structure, or that concert tickets have a different pricing structure, or my time as a consultant has a different pricing structure, is really not relevant. The products are different.

Comment: @KateGregory I see your point, and I'm sure you're more informed than I am, so really, I'm not disputing your point. I was just noticing that from a layman's POV, looking around on the news, it seems that airlines' peculiar ticket pricing system is not working that well, especially lately, and they're using more and more a "normal" (sorry) pricing system for selling other stuff on the side in order to compensate. So I was just wondering if this can be considered as evidence that airlines' pricing system is not so great for them (or it might just be that I'm completly missing a bigger picture)

Comment: @Shivan: It's only evidence that aircraft are extremely expensive to run, and if airlines charged the same price for every ticket independent of sale time, you wouldn't get as many people buying tickets. You really want to fill up those planes. Even with a phone this logic does sort of apply when you consider that people buying it shortly after launch are going to be contributing more to recouping the project cost than those who buy it for half the price two years later.

Comment: @ShivanDragon and concert tickets ever more are set to name as well, precisely to prevent speculators from buying them all up 2 minutes after sales start and then reselling them on eBay for 10-100 times the list price, which is exactly what speculators have been doing.

Comment: In addition, also consider that a plane and a concert have a limited number of seats, while a phone manufacturer _usually_ can just produce as many as he needs to meet demand, if he wants to (and he does).

Comment: This also stops travel agents from buying 200 seats on a plane when they're really cheap 12 months before, and then "transferring" them to customers for 5x the price, losing the airline a lot of money.

Comment: @ShivanDragon The fact is that the airline industry has not been particularly profitabl lately, with a lot of competition and very low margins (compared to other industries or, indeed, Apple). So if it was not able to play these games and sell at least some tickets for a higher price, something would have to give.

Answer (score 14):

Another factor--sometimes life happens and you can't fly.  In the old days you could simply sell your ticket to someone else, now you either have to eat a hefty change fee or lose it outright.  That's money in their pockets that they didn't use to get.

Comment: With most airlines, in such situations You can ask for a refund.

Comment: @ISAE most situations? Not really true. A large number of tickets sold are cheap tickets that are non-refundable. Generally, only "full price" tickets are refundable, and they tend to be expensive.

Comment: I'd say that it's possible to get a voucher for the value you paid, but I've never seen a cash refund... at least without some type of fee. I had to make a change (flight + hotel) I noticed 15 minutes after purchasing, and the hotel 'no-refund' policy wanted to try and charge $80 to adjust it. The hotel themselves had no issue changing dates for free.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier In my experience, it depends mainly on the airline. A decent airline will have an interest to satisfy the customers, and they'll offer you some kind of refund, perhaps through a voucher.

Comment: Taxes, however, often are refundable because the conditions for those are set by the authorities. Some other fees may similarly be refundable independent from the ticket.

Comment: @fiksdal no, it was right as it was

Comment: @AakashM Since English is not my native language, I'm not going to claim to be sure. I've [asked about it on ELLSE](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/100674/26160) instead. From your profile it looks like you may be British, so I'm certainly not going to claim to have a better knowledge of English grammar than you.

Answer (score 6):

Airlines aren't just in the business of selling "tickets" to seats. They are selling tickets to seats on *different days.* It's the "different days's" part that means that the same seat will sell for a lower price "in advance" and a higher price closer to the flight date.

If you could re-sell the ticket to a friend, you could (theoretically) get the advantage of the "different days." More to the point, speculators could do the same. The airline doesn't want to allow this opportunity.

The best solution is for the airline to refund your "cheap" ticket, so they can re-sell the same ticket at a higher price on a "different day" to another passenger. Many airlines will do this. Some will not, because they don't value customer service/relations enough.

Answer (score 5):

This may result in an abuse situation.
You can think that a non-registered travel group bought so many tickets with different names on a certain flight, then start selling the tickets but for larger price.

Unchangeable tickets will get rid of this situation and only registered travel companies can have legal deals with the airlines.

Comment: Number of years ago I saw an ad where a young man was seeking a young woman named <specific female name> to share a free week-long flight and Banff ski trip.  Seems he'd paid for the vacation for himself and his girl-friend <same specific name>, and then broken up with her.  No refund, no credit, but he if he found someone with the same name, the airline couldn't tell the difference

Comment: So you mean that it's better, when the flight company does this abuse itself?

Answer (score 2):

Another reason might be that airlines tend to overbook planes, if they can. They expect a certain percentage of passengers to cancel their flight and want to prevent empty seats. If everyone found a replacement, there would not be enough seats on the plane for everyone!

Comment: How common is this really??

Comment: @curiousdannii not very. Airlines do know they're going to have a certain percentage of no-shows, but it's not a very high percentage on most flights. There's some flights with many no-shows, and on those they sometimes go overboard on the overselling. Flights like CUR-AMS where every flight tends to get several dozen drugs couriers either getting cold feet and never showing at the airport or caught trying to get through customs and be arrested. On such flights they safely sell more than one or two more seats than there are available positions.

Comment: @jwenting in the USA overbooking is absolutely everyday, several airlines have automated processes where you are offered a "bump voucher" during checkin, kiosk or on-line.

Answer (score 2):

I realize there's already an accepted answer about "yield management" but, while their price discrimination strategy certainly exacerbates their rationale, I think that misses the point.  I think the bigger reason is quite simply that they can get away with it.  Let me expand on that.  When most people book an airline ticket it's because they're planning to fly themselves so they discount the chances that they'd want to transfer the ticket to someone else.  This means when most people book a flight they're completely willing to agree that the seat they're buying can only be used by them even though objectively that's an unreasonable condition of the sale.

There's frequently this assumption that speculators being involved means gouging, well they will certainly *try* to gouge people but there's no guarantee they'd be successful.  There's certainly a guarantee that buying a group of plane tickets that are refundable will be a profitable strategy since any tickets that can't be sold for a profit will be refunded the original purchase price.  However, most tickets are nonrefundable and, as such, this strategy wouldn't work out so well.

Comment: Most flights these days are almost full. That suggests that it would be a completely viable strategy to buy tickets early and selling them later on at, say, 90% of what the buyer would have to pay to get a ticket from the airline on that date. And that's without anybody getting gouged: the passenger gets a discount on the airline's price and the reseller still makes a tidy profit.

Comment: @DavidRicherby This sounds viable except that the airlines wouldn't sit idly by while that happened.  For one, they'd stop discounting the fares for the far future.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the airlines change their policies, remove restrictions and make the tickets transferable, this would create a whole new market niche for resellers. If this happen there would be many complications related to liability of the resellers, quality guarantees, safety rules and more. It would be virtually impossible for the airlines to operate within the same legal terms, as the do now.

When I read the original questions and then the answer that explains "yield management" or "revenue management" I'd asked myself would I fly on the ticket I bough through an auction website? I would not.

Comment: Have you ever used Priceline?

Answer (score -2):

Transfers can be two ways. If they have to register the transfer then of course they should be able to control the flow of cash. HOWEVER, if they don't register it, as for example might the situation if I gave you my bus ticket then, apart from  the economic factors, there are clearly a few accountability and safety factors.

1. If the plane crashes for some reason, the airline would not be in a
   position to state who was on board. So they would then end up
   reporting that the ticket seller/donor had died, when in fact it was
   the recipient.
2. If the plane is hijacked, or even brought down by terrorists, it
   could be that the terrorists were the ones who bought the re-sold
   ticket. And the airline would think it was the original buyer.
3. Ditto for the situation where someone might have been smuggling
   drugs or other contraband.

I'm sure you can come up with other safety and security aspects if you think hard enough.

Comment: 1, 2, 3: All wrong, as there are loads of controls before boarding. You can't board without a passport/ID and it gets read electronically, so there's no overhead in storing the data instead of just checking it against the database.