Can I change the passenger on Wizz Air?
Is it possible to change a passenger on a flight booked with Wizz Air and what is the fee for that? It says there is a 60 Euro fee for changing the name of the passenger but is that for actually changing the passenger to a new passenger or just for changing the name of the passenger booked before?

You almost certainly cannot change the passenger, see https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/37439/46. You might be able to change the name (recently I absentmindedly booked a ticket as Kate, but that is not what it says in my passport) and many airlines do not charge for that, but you will be asked to prove that it's still the same person, you're just fixing a typo or a short form or a middle initial or the like.

While I have no experience with them, the Wizz Air website tells us:

that you can actually change passengers:


that changes to the name of an existing passenger are free:



NAME CHANGES
Change the name of the passenger online up to 3 hours before the scheduled time of departure!
It will be required to pay a name change fee of ‎€60.00 per flight:
Please note that if the name change is requested via the Wizz Air Call Centre, the Call Centre Transaction Fee will be charged.
Name change is free of charge online if a misspelled name or a typo needs to be corrected, such as:

if there are maximum 3 characters to be changed in the name added to the booking
if an abbreviated name needs to be extended an the (e.g.: John T. Smith) to a full name (e.g.: John Thomas Smith) in order to match the travel document
if the gender (title) of the name added to the booking needs to be changed.

It is possible to make only make one free name change correction in the booking.
In case first name and last name is mixed up, please contact the Wizz Air Call Centre for requesting the correction. This correction is free of charge and the Call Centre Transaction Fee will not be charged.

Another page says that changing a maiden name to a married name is also free.
So, my understanding is that, basically:

Nearly any change of name matching the same person is free
Other changes, which mean a different person, incur the fee.


No.
You need to cancel the existing ticket and buy a new one. Depending on terms of the specific ticket you may get a partial refund or travel credit from the cancellation and you may be able to use this towards the new ticket. But again, that depends a lot on the details.

In any cases, even on a fully fixed ticket, you can always get the taxes back

I don’t think this is correct. The Wizzair FAQ gives no conditions for a name change. They actually say it’s feee for minor changes (typos, first/last name swap, gender change, maiden name to married name change…) and have a fee for changing the name so that is likely to be for an actual change of passenger.
